# Setting constraints to zero in extended Hamiltonian

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I am dealing with a system that has some secondary constraints. I am trying to use Dirac-Bergmann procedure by following chapter 10 of Ashok Das, Lectures on Quantum Field Theory ( 2021, Second Edition ). Let me denote my extended hamiltonian as
$$ H_{Extended} = H_{canonical} + \lambda_i \phi^i_p + \lambda_i \phi^i_s $$
where $\phi^i_p$ are the primary constraints, and $\phi^i_s$ are the secondary  constraints. All of these are second-class constraints.

I am confused by two examples given in the book:

Example 1 describes a particle moving on a sphere. Example 2 is about the dirac field theory.

In both the examples we construct Dirac brackets. We also determine the lagrange multipliers in both examples.
Now in example 1, the author sets all the constraints to zero in equation (10.55) because the well engineered Dirac brackets already ensure that constraints are compatible with equations of motion. But in example 2, he substitutes the value of lagrange multipliers in equation(10.114). I was expecting that in example 2 also he will set the constraints to zero after finding Dirac brackets.

**Coming back to more general discussion, here is my question?**

Should one set $\phi^i_p$ and $\phi^i_s$ to zero ? Or should one substitute the value of $\lambda_i$?

Or does the answer differ for primary and secondary constraints ?

( I can cite more the actual equations from the book or provide more context. But hopefully my question is more general than that .)